# Pinterest style layout - when some images have the same height

Tags: jquery, css, pinterest, masonry

I'm working with Freewall.js to create a Pinterest style layout. It looks good except when some images at the topmost have the same height. Then it looks like a grid instead of a masonry.

Anyway can the height be varied for images with same height (if they are appearing next to each other)?

I don't have control over the image sizes, as it will be uploaded by a third party.

I'm using the basic [pinterest layout from Freewall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/pinterest-layout.html)

Here's the code:

JS:

```
var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.brick',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 200,
            cellH: 'auto',
            onResize: function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            }
        });

        wall.container.find('.brick img').load(function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="freewall" class="free-wall">
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="i/photo/1.jpg" width="100%">
            <div class="info">
                <h3>Freewall</h3>
                <h5>Pinterest layout</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="i/photo/2.jpg" width="100%">
            <div class="info">
                <h3>Freewall</h3>
                <h5>Pinterest layout</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
...
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you just not reorder the images based on their height so that no two images with the same height sat next to each other?

Comment: Can that be done? I'm sorry, I'm not that advanced in JS to tinker too much with Freewall, I tried but couldn't figure out how to move the bricks around. Do I have to rearrange the html itself for that? Thanks.

Comment: Does freewall make the XHR call or do you?

Comment: I think its done from my side. Hmmmm.. So, if I can check the image dimensions when that call is made. I can do something with that?

Comment: yeah, to me it seems easier than trying to twist and bend the plugin, if you post that code (probably in a new answer, maybe not) then we can take a look at that for you